# Practical Tips: Mathematical research and discoveries

Tags: reference-request, big-list, advice

> *How to be when you are working on something innovative? What to do if there is a chance (even the $1\%$) that your
>   work is leading you to something original?*

For example what have I do if I don't know mathematicians that I don't trust to ask him? Is a good idea to talk about your results to someone, even if are not real results?

> **Question:**
>
> What do you do when you feel like that?
>
> I'm looking for a **list** or links about Math.SE questions,
>   of **practical tips** to use studying about something that you
>   feel innovative  providing a new solution.

I am interested for books about how the mathematicians' research, as well.

> *Here the link to the same question on [AccademiaSE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/practical-tips-mathematical-research-and-discoveries)*

Comment: A good strategy would be to tell people that you have original content that you cannot share with somebody because they might steal it. Better yet, tweet that you have an elegant proof for a big conjecture, but it unfortunately won’t fit the 140-characters-restriction.

Comment: Write it up, then ask experts in the field if they think it is original, keeping record of the correspondence. If they believe it's original, submit it to a journal. If it is accepted, you can feel you have accomplished something. At any rate, don't be too distressed if it turns out someone thought of it already, or if you have some mistake: this is fairly common.

Comment: @K.Stm. But I do not understand where is the advantage. Is intended to be sarcastic?

Comment: Also, this is not a constructive question. It sounds more like you want to discuss paranoia and excitement about your own personal project.

Comment: @rschwieb a list of links related, or similar question is not enough real for you? Ps:I don't want to discuss nothing, I just want to know if there are some common tips about this, valid for all, or the most used behaviour.

Comment: @MphLee Please see the FAQ about what questions are appropriate to ask here.

Comment: @MphLee It’s a joke, hinting at [Fermat’s Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_last_theorem#Fermat.27s_conjecture).

Comment: @rschwieb a list of links related, or similar question is not enough "real" (costructive) for you? I don't want to discuss nothing, I just want to know if there are some common tips about this, valid for all, or the most used behaviour. I read the faq but I don't understand how is related with this question since there is a tag too for these kind of questions: Big lists/ References.
By the way I never told about my project so I dont know what you are talking about with "paranoia and excitement", I'm sure you can't find these things in my original question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/why-my-question-was-closed

Comment: I would argue that this is a valid question and should be re-opened. It is related to the field of maths and certainly can be answered with answers supported by "specific expertise". It is similar in spirit to many other questions asked here, e.g. in the related bar on the right hand side.

Comment: @MphLee I apologize, I may have imagined too many things when reading the question. Regardless, this is still off topic. I think what you are really looking for is academia.stackexchange.

Comment: @TomOldfield I think if you reread it, there is nothing specific to mathematics here. One could ask any of this about *any* field of research. Don't you think it belongs in academia.stackexchange?

Comment: @rschwieb Whilst it is certainly true that it could be asked about any field of research, I think that the answers would depend greatly on the field. For example, the asker indicates that they don't know any mathematicians that they trust to ask. This could be due to a fear of plagiarism. I would argue that plagiarism is much harder to do in, say, an experimental science where specific experimental equipment and processes are required to conduct research, compared to mathematics where all you need is to have written something down. (continued)

Comment: I would also imagine that it is much easier to try and apply new ideas to other related topics in maths than it is in an experimental science, which would again require more time and expense to carry out experiments. If the asker really wants an answer specific to maths, I think it is okay for the question to be here. There is of course the option for them to post it on academia as well, and link the posts together. This is an often accepted (and encouraged) way to ask a question that may belong in multiple places.

Comment: @TomOldfield and that was my problem, but anyways the answers to my question can give me a sort of "modus operandi" of how to work on mathematical problems when you feel you are doing something new or when you think to be close to discovering something important.

Comment: @TomOldfield "I would argue that plagiarism is much harder to do in, say, an experimental science ... compared to mathematics"... And would you have any data to support that claim? All three most recent cases I can personally remember are in experimental sciences (and the experimetal results were faked all right).

Comment: @Did No, I don't have any data. I'm not talking about how often plagiarism occurs, which is something that I have very little idea about, just how easy it would be, if a more experienced mathematician was handed some good work from a less experienced one, say. I certainly don't think it is $\texit{likely}$ to happen, and I don't think that it's something the asker should be worried about, but I can see why they $\textit{might}$ be worried about it.

Comment: @TomOldfield Right, thanks. You see, to explain the amount of plagiarism, the fact that proofs in maths often do not require experimental work dwarfs when compared to other (inter-related) factors such as: publication pressure (where if not in maths can one hear the phrase "he/she publishes *too much*" about a candidate?), power structure in the labs (often lighter in maths than in other fields), need for financing (idem), focus on a proper attribution of results (almost maniacal in maths when compared to other fields), highest prizes going to *young* people, and so on.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since it looks like people like the question, I may as well post my answer as an answer. It was sincere, after all:

Write it up, preferably using LaTeX. (That is a "trade skill" for mathematics writers.) It will be important that you have this ready, if you are seriously interested in taking credit.

Then ask experts in the field if they think it is original, keeping record of the correspondence. There is little to be worried about concerning academic dishonesty here, especially if you keep track of correspondence in an organized way. You don't have to give them your entire write-up if you don't trust them. You can just convey your main ideas, and if they have appeared before, you will likely be pointed to the publication. The odds are that if your work was worthwhile, it would hardly be reproducable in a short amount of time. Remember that you must have been working on it for a while, so there must be some content that took some thinking.

If they believe it's original, submit it to a journal. If it is accepted, you can feel you have accomplished something. You can still submit it if your experts say it's not worth publishing, but if you ignore valid reasons that they have, you may face some embarassment.

At any rate, don't be too distressed if it turns out someone thought of it already, or if you have some mistake: this is fairly common. A *lot* of people have thought about mathematics in the past few thousand years, so there is a large chance of paths crossing :)

In conclusion, you are probably not going to get anywhere without talking with some experts on the topic you are researching. It is reasonable to consult them, exposing the core part of your ideas. It is unlikely that the body of your work will be totally hijacked.

Comment: good answer! But I'll wait a bit for other for a more complete view.

Comment: Now I'm really paying the price for my earlier closure vote :) 10 votes, and I can't get any points because after voting to close, your posts are apparently automatically converted to CW

Comment: I do not think is bad because I was not interested in reputation, I think these must be common knowledges for mathematicans. Very useful tips for everyone interested in research. About why, @robjohn made it CW, and was a good idea imo. Even if I wanted to see more answers.. :(